# Using multiple joins in

Tags: sql

there is a good way to do multiple joins in one Query?

I did not tried before to do more than one Join in Query and I hope there is be nice & genteel way for doing it.

thanks!!

Comment: Just add more joins... that is the whole trick and any good book or tutorial on SQL would have shown that.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible:

```
select *
from table_1 as t1
  join table_2 as t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
  join table_3 as t3 on t3.table2_id = t2.id
```